# I want to take union on objects of two array based on their id

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let suppose I have two array

```js
let array1 = [{id: 1,name: "a"},{id: 2,name: "b"}]
let array2 = [{id: 1,name: 'c'},{id: 3,name: 'd'}]
```

and I want the resulting array to be like so

```
let result = [{id: 1,name: 'c'},{id: 2,name: 'b'},{id: 3,name: 'd'}]
```

So if the second array has an object and the first array also has an object with the same id then replace the first object with the second array object.
Currently, I have try below code but it checks for each value to match and I want to match on id based only

```
const uniqueArray = this.servicesdata.filter((item, index) => {
        const _item = JSON.stringify(item);
        return (
          index ===
          this.servicesdata.findIndex(obj => {
            return JSON.stringify(obj) === _item;
          })
        );
      });
      console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Comment: 1) Please show us what have you tried so far to achieve this. 2) Why there is no object with `name: a` in the `result`

Comment: because the object with name: a and object with name: c have same id that's why it will be replaced by object from array 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `O(NlogN)` approach.

```js
let array1 = [{id: 1,name: "a"},{id: 2,name: "b"}] // Let's say its size is N1
let array2 = [{id: 1,name: 'c'},{id: 3,name: 'd'}] // Let's say its size is N2
let duplicate  = new Set() // A set to check for duplicate elements
let result = array2
array2.forEach((item)=>{ // O(N2logN2)
    duplicate.add(item.id);
})
array1.forEach((item)=>{ // O(N1logN2)
    // If `duplicate` does NOT have `item.id`, that means it's unique in array1, so add it to result
    // Otherwise, skip it because for duplicates, we want value from array2
    if(!duplicate.has(item.id))
        result.push(item);
})
// Overall complexity of approach - O(N2logN2) + O(N1logN2) ==> O(NlogN)
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'c' },
  { id: 3, name: 'd' },
  { id: 2, name: 'b' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash you can use [unionBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#unionBy):

```js
let array1 = [{id: 1,name: "a"},{id: 2,name: "b"}]
let array2 = [{id: 1,name: 'c'},{id: 3,name: 'd'}]
console.log(_.unionBy(array2, array1, 'id'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```